# What is the best way to define onload method when providing JS file using JavaScript notation

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

I have the following code to be included in my html at the header part in my application,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
        onload="if (typeof (module) === 'object') { window.jQuery = window.$ = module.exports; }"></script>
```

To solve the above problem, I have done in the following way but it does not work,

Inclusion of JS file while using AbstractJavaScriptExtension,

```
@JavaScript({
   "scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"})
```

The following is the code in the connector,

```
window.de_qsoft_vaadin_ui_Widget = function() {

    var element = this.getElement();


    This is commented code to check if this could be one of the solution I think.
    //$(document).ready(function() {
    //  if (typeof (module) === 'object')
    //  { 
    //      window.jQuery = window.$ = module.exports; 
    //  }
    //}(jQuery));

    this.onStateChange = function() {

        if (typeof (module) === 'object')
        { 
            window.jQuery = window.$ = module.exports; 
        }

    };
};
```

Please advice.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Are there errors in the JS console? Have you verified that the jQuery file is successfully loaded in the browser? Is your `onStateChange` handler actually run? Is it run early enough?